# mysql Query Insert into or update when entry already exists

Tags: mysql

I have the following query (user_id isn't and can't be primary key as there are many entries from each user depending on another column of the table). I used duplicate key but doesnt work. It still adds a new row. Any thoughts?

```
INSERT INTO profile (user_id, correct) VALUES(". $user_id . ", correct + 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE correct=correct+1
```

**EDIT**
So if row exists for this user_id, I want to go update this entry and SET correct = correct+1 and not make a new entry with user_id and correct=1 again

Comment: Your question doesn't quite make sense to me. If `user_id` is not unique, then how do you know which row you want to update? And you make it sound like `user_id` plus some other (unnamed) column should, together, be the primary key; but then you have an INSERT statement that doesn't set a value for that other column. I think you may want to re-examine your table design, and make sure that you have a sensible primary key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO profile (user_id, correct)
VALUES ($user_id, 0);

UPDATE profile SET correct = correct + 1 
WHERE  user_id = $user_id;  -- updates 0 to 1
```

Or:

```
UPDATE profile SET correct = correct + 1 
WHERE  user_id = $user_id;
```

If not found:

```
INSERT INTO profile (user_id, correct)
VALUES ($user_id, 1);
```

I prefer the second variant.
The first variant requires that the `user_id` has a UNIQUE constraint. (PRIMARY KEY counts.)